# What does symmetry mean when plotting Real vs Imaginary Components of FFT of a Periodic Time Series

Tags: math, signal-processing, fft

[image]

As the subject says, What does the symmetry mean when graphing real vs imaginary components of a FFT? And does the clustering imply periodicity in the data?

I ask this because I did a project with predicting sunspot count with a neural network and had to find the periodicity of the data (and used FFT which worked).

Someone recommended I look at graphing the real vs imaginary components, but I don't understand what I am looking at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fourier transform of any real-valued signal will have [Hermitian symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_function), meaning the transform values of the positive frequencies and negative frequencies will be complex conjugates of each other.  Therefore the real values are the same, and the imaginary values are negatives of each other, as your picture shows.

It would probably be more interesting to drop the negative frequencies and do your graph again.

For your second question, your result appears to be clustered around 0,0, so no, the clustering does not imply periodicity.  Large values in the transform imply periodicity, at the related frequency.

However, you have two large components, one primarily real and one primarily imaginary.  Another way of thinking of "real in the frequency domain" is "like a cosine in the time domain", while "imaginary in the frequency domain" is "like a sine in the time domain."  Your data set probably doesn't start exactly on a sunspot cycle, so the cycle looks like the combination of a sine and cosine.  If you slide the data set, the relative amplitudes of the real and imaginary parts will probably change.

I had earlier suggested that the phase difference might imply differing activity in summer and winter, but that would show up as a component at twice the base frequency.

Comment: For sunspot counts, the periodicity is likely around 11 years, and there's probably a phase shift (difference between start of data set and start of a sunspot cycle) that results in both real and imaginary components at that period in the frequency domain.

Comment: @Jim - good point, that totally slipped my mind.  Thanks, I've edited the answer to include it.